# Replace a string in Dataweave during XML to XML conversion

Tags: mule, esb, dataweave

My input XMl is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DEBMAS01>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
  <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
  <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
  <IDOCTYP>DEBMAS01</IDOCTYP>
  <MESTYP>DEBMAS</MESTYP>
  <SNDPOR>MULESOFT</SNDPOR>
  <SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
  <SNDPRN>MULESOFT</SNDPRN>
  <RCVPOR>MULESOFT</RCVPOR>
  <RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
  <RCVPRN>MULESOFT</RCVPRN>
</EDI_DC40>
<E1KNA1M SEGMENT="1">
  <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
  <KUNNR>0000099500</KUNNR>
  <KTOKD>ZAG2</KTOKD>
  <LAND1>SK</LAND1>
  <NAME1>Mulesoft 99003 2nd</NAME1>
  <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
  <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
</E1KNA1M>
```

My expected output XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DEBMAS01>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
  <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
  <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
  <IDOCTYP>DEBMAS01</IDOCTYP>
  <MESTYP>DEBMAS</MESTYP>
  <SNDPOR>PROJECT1</SNDPOR>
  <SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
  <SNDPRN>MULESOFT</SNDPRN>
  <RCVPOR>MULESOFT</RCVPOR>
  <RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
  <RCVPRN>MULESOFT</RCVPRN>
</EDI_DC40>
<E1KNA1M SEGMENT="1">
  <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
  <KUNNR>0000099500</KUNNR>
  <KTOKD>ZAG2</KTOKD>
  <LAND1>SK</LAND1>
  <NAME1>Mulesoft 99003 2nd</NAME1>
  <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
  <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
</E1KNA1M>
```

Here i just want to replace the string in SNDPOR tag from "MULESOFT" to "PROJECT1". I have achieved this using XSLT. But now i want to achieve this using Dataweave script. Kindly help.

Comment: Why you don't read the documentation is quite clear, you don't need someone else do all the work for you https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after going through the docs. Thanks to Rocco for enlightening me.
The solution is

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
--- 
DEBMAS01 :{(payload map {
IDOC @(BEGIN:payload.DEBMAS01.IDOC.@BEGIN):{
    EDI_DC40 @(SEGMENT:payload.DEBMAS01.IDOC.EDI_DC40.@SEGMENT):payload.DEBMAS01.IDOC.EDI_DC40 mapObject {
    "$$" : $ unless "$$" ~="SNDPOR" otherwise "PROJECT1"
    },
    E1KNA1M @(SEGMENT:payload.DEBMAS01.IDOC.E1KNA1M.@SEGMENT):payload.DEBMAS01.IDOC.E1KNA1M mapObject {
        "$$": $
    }
}
})
}
```